# Segmentation Error: Quadratic Equation Solver from text file in C

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I'm trying to write a quadratic equation solver that reads the roots from a text file called qinput.txt and writes the roots to qoutput.txt. The program is compiling properly, but when I try to run it I receive a segmentation error.

[This MIT page](http://web.mit.edu/10.001/Web/Tips/tips_on_segmentation.html) talks a lot about segmentation faults from scanf and printf, but I can't quite figure it out.

I have pasted my code below.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main(){
  float a,b,c;
  float d,root1,root2;
  FILE *qinput;
  FILE *qoutput;

  fscanf(qinput,"%f%f%f",&a,&b,&c);

  d = b * b - 4 * a * c;

  if(d < 0){

    fprintf(qoutput,"Roots of quadratic equation are: ");
    fprintf(qoutput,"%.3f%+.3fi",-b/(2*a),sqrt(-d)/(2*a));
    fprintf(qoutput,"%.3f%+.3fi",-b/(2*a),-sqrt(-d)/(2*a));

    return 0;
  }
  else if(d==0){
   fprintf(qoutput,"Both roots are equal.\n");

   root1 = -b /(2* a);
   fprintf(qoutput,"Root of quadratic equation is: %.3f ",root1);

   return 0;
  }
  else{
   fprintf(qoutput,"Roots are real numbers.\n");

   root1 = ( -b + sqrt(d)) / (2* a);
   root2 = ( -b - sqrt(d)) / (2* a);
   fprintf(qoutput,"Roots of quadratic equation are: %.3f , %.3f",root1,root2);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you try asking superman first?

Comment: Your output isn't very readable.  You get very close to smushing the two values for the complex roots together (there's an `i` separating them).  You should end output with newlines.

Comment: The input and output streams seem to be `null`. You have to set the values for `qinput` and `qoutput` before using them. You seem to be trying to read a text file `qinput.txt`. You have to open the file using `fopen` and set the value of the variable `qinput` to the stream you get from `fopen`. Same with output file.

Comment: "... talks a lot about segmentation faults from scanf and printf" yet this code is not using `scanf(), printf()`.  It is using `fscanf(), fprintf()`.  Try `FILE *qinput = stdin;
  FILE *qoutput = stdout;`

Comment: I think you want to use standard input/output instead of file, so replace fscanf/fprintf with simple scanf/printf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're getting a segmentation fault because you don't initialize the `FILE` pointers `qinput` and `qoutput` to anything. When you don't initialize them, those variables don't have any meaningful values - it's like you're taking some random memory location and attempting to interpret whatever gibberish happens to be there as a `FILE` object. This causes a segmentation fault because your program accesses a "segment" of memory that it's not supposed to.

What you need to do is create a `FILE` object that corresponds to the file `qinput.txt` and store a pointer to it in the variable `qinput`. And similarly for `qoutput`. You could do this using the `fopen()` function. Have a look around the web for a good reference or tutorial about how to use that function.